# Anchor link doesnt more after form submitt

Tags: asp-classic

```
<a href="account_step.asp?oid= %=request.querystring("oid")%>&cid=
<%=request.querystring("cid")%>&sid=<%=request.querystring("sid")%>
#cert">Certification</a>
```

Thats just one example of one of my long anchor links Works fine. But when I submit a form which also uses a hyper-link and a save variable to redirect, and then click on the anchor links like the one above, it goes to the wrong tab page.

```
oid=<%=request.querystring("oid")%>&cid=<%=request.querystring("cid")%>
&sid=<%=request.querystring("sid")%>&save=true#more
```

Doies anyone know of a similar problem going from one anchor link to another?

Answer (score 0):

> But when I submit a form which also uses a hyper-link and a save
>   variable to redirect, and then click on the anchor links like the one
>   above, it goes to the wrong tab page.

What I suspect is happening is that you're `POST`ing your form and since those variables are looking for query string variables, they're not found on the next page.

The quickest fix would be to update your form like so:

```
<%
Dim oid, cid, sid

oid = Request.QueryString("oid")
cid = Request.QueryString("cid")
sid = Request.QueryString("sid")
%>
<form action="formpage.asp?id=<%=oid %>&cid=<%=cid %>&sid=<%=sid %>&save=true#more" method="post">
```